# Playing Multiple Videos Using Storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, video, viewcontroller

I am very new to xcode and app development, I have figured out how to play a video in a single view point application but for my first app I am using storyboards. I have created a table view storyboard application with "no coding", I can code java, but using storyboards is so much easier, I want to put in videos into some of my view controllers but do not know how. When I try creating an outlet in ViewController.h it does appear in any of my view controllers? How does linking these outlets work ?

Summing up I want to play videos in "storyboards" not in just one single view controller, "in multiple view controllers".

If anyone can help I will show my upmost graditude, I have tried my best researching and found stackoverflow is the best site for help :) thanks you all.